# Edit link broken for a question

Tags: support, edits, firefox

I asked this:

[What is the semantic for the modulo operator x % y, when y is 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901303/what-is-the-semantic-for-the-modulo-operator-x-y-when-y-is-0/19901346?noredirect=1#comment29608654_19901346)

And the edit link below the question is:

[Edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19901303/edit)

When I press it, I get a 'Page not Found' error. Why?

**Notes:**

- Using Firefox 25 on Win7.
- Clearing the cache does not work.
- Restarting Firefox *does* work for some strange reason, without disabling anything.

Comment: Strange. I can see the edit window opened and I'd have proved it you by editing your question(but just editing it for the sake of it and rolling it back is a horrible thing to do). Nevertheless, it seems to be some cache issue. Try to clear the cache and reload the page.

Comment: No repro here. I can see the edit link properly.. I can also edit the question with inline editing.

Comment: Disable your browser's add-ons, plugins and user scripts. Most likely one of those interfere with JavaScript somehow and causing this problem.

Comment: Hah ha, can't edit this question either! A self-reproducing bug... anyway, clearing the cache does not Work. I use Firefox 25. Let's see if disabling extensions works.

Comment: Well, if restarting Firefox solve this (even temporary) it means that's not a bug in Stack Exchange side, but on your browser. Try using Chrome from own experience it's more stable than Firefox.